# JSON POST isnt working Windows Phone 7

Tags: json, silverlight, windows-phone-7, post

I dont think this is working, I was wondering if you could spot anything wrong with my code and how I could fix it please? Im new very to this and not sure whether to use web request, web response or anything. Whats the most basic way of doing POST to json?

Thank you

```
private void btnSaveCar_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string url = "http://......";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(ProcessResponse), request);
        }



    private void ProcessResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asyncResult.AsyncState;
        Stream streamResp = request.EndGetRequestStream(asyncResult);
        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Car));
        Car newCar = new Car():

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {

            newCar.Condition = txtCondition.Text;
            newCar.Colour = txtColour.Text;
            newCar.RegistrationNumber = txtReg.Text;
            newCar.Model = txtModel.Text;
            short.TryParse(txtYear.Text, out newCar.Year);
            short chassisNumber;
            short.TryParse(txtChassisNumber.Text, out chassisNumber);
            newCar.ChassisNumber = chassisNumber;
            newCar.BodyStyle = txtBodyStyle.Text;
            try
            {
                ser.WriteObject(streamResp, newCar);
                NavigationService.GoBack();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("didnt work :(");
            }


        });
    }
```

Comment: Which bit isn't working? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is incomplete, you should call the [Request.BeginGetResponse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.begingetresponse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method after writing the data to the Request stream!

Look at [this sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx) on how to do a POST with WebRequest (do take notice that the sample is for .NET 4.0 but I think you'll get the idea).

I'd still suggest that you use [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) instead of going with the basic WebRequest to save some development time!

Comment: what should I put for the state object in the BeginGetResponse() method?

Comment: Pass it the webrequest object again, as you did with BeginGetRequestStream before.

Comment: it says it has invalid arguements, do I have to make an object containing that "request" item?

Comment: is there another link u can send me, this one doesnt make sense with BeginGetResponse()

Comment: Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetrequeststream.aspx), it's for .NET 4, but I think this one will work on Windows Phone too!

Comment: im getting an error saying "The remote server returned an error: NotFound." on the HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult); line

what do I do?

Comment: Seems your service url is not correct OR you are unable to get to the server; open internet explorer in the phone and test the service url!

Comment: oh my, the service has gone down I think cos its spelt correctly